# Could I voluntarily surrender my CMD vs. an allied bull rush?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat-maneuver, forced-movement

I was reading up on various home brew remedies for what things might look like when a very big person throws a very small friend further out on the field of battle. Those are all interesting, and relevant to my purposes here, but that's background.

The actual question - if the circumstance arose that I would prefer to surrender my CMD, or maybe reduce it to the inherent 10 + size modifier built into it, is there any explicit rule allowing me to do so?

Comment: are you using rules as written to just ask what the rules say?  The tag makes sense since Bull Rush for extra movement might draw hate speech without it, but I just want to check that you are *also* asking for a pedantic reading of the CMD rules here.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer, pedantics are expected and appreciated.

Comment: Excellent, that's what we try to reserve the [rules-as-written] tag for. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short Answer: There is no explicit rule that does everything,  but you can achieve the desired effect.

**PF Core Rulebook page 199**

> **Combat Maneuver Defense** Each character and creature 
>   has a Combat Maneuver Defense (or CMD) that represents 
>   its ability to resist combat maneuvers. A creature’s CMD is 
>   determined using the following formula
>
> CMD = 10 + Base attack bonus + Strength modifier + Dexterity modifier + special size modifier
>
> [...]
>
> A creature can also add any circumstance, deflection, 
>   dodge, insight, luck, morale, profane, and sacred bonuses 
>   to AC to its CMD.
>
> Any penalties to a creature’s AC also 
>   apply to its CMD. A flat-footed creature does not add its 
>   Dexterity bonus to its CMD.

I would interpret "ability to resist combat maneuvers" as including passive resistance which is supported by size being included as a factor. However, you could make the argument that it only includes active resistance, in which case you could fully waive your CMD.

The next step is then to minify the factors one by one.

## Dexterity Modifier

Using the Helpless Defender rules can help with this.

**PF Core Rulebook page 197**

> **Helpless Defenders**
>   A helpless opponent is someone who is bound, sleeping, 
>   paralyzed, unconscious, or otherwise at your mercy.
>
> **Regular Attack** A helpless character takes a –4 penalty 
>   to AC against melee attacks. In addition, a helpless 
>   character is treated as having a Dexterity of 0, giving him 
>   a –5 penalty to AC against both melee and ranged attacks 
>   (for a total of –9 against melee and –5 against ranged). A 
>   helpless character is also flat-footed.

If you choose to not put up any resistance, you are "otherwise at the mercy" of your party member. Thus, all the effects attributed to Helpless Defenders apply to you, including being flat-footed and having a Dexterity modifier of -5.

After reading [Can being flat-footed actually improve your AC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/65003/36305), particularly the section on negative dexterity being considered a penalty, it seems that the -5 applies seperately as as an AC penalty. However, since flat-footed characters do not add their Dexterity bonus to their CMD, this does not apply the penalty twice, so it is only a -5.

Depending on your DM, you might also be required to make some sort of DEX check to avoid falling over (since your DEX is being treated as 0, this would be a bad situation).

## Remaining Modifiers - BAB and Strength

I am not aware of any way to eliminate BAB or STR modifier at will directly, but you could certainly argue not to add them if your character is not resisting based purely on their descriptions as things your character actively does.

Since the rules allow circumstance modifiers to be added to CMD, you could also argue that the characters lack of willingness to use Strength or fighting skills produces a set of circumstances in which the Strength and BAB are cancelled out by circumstance modifiers.

If you combine the above, you now have:

> CMD = 10 + special size modifier

And possibly

> CMD = 10 + special size modifier - 5

## Explicit but Inconvenient Methods

This doesn't seem to be the focus of your question, but you could acquire a variety of magical effects explicitely described in the rulebook that would change your BAB, STR, and DEX.

Specifically, if you could acquire a cursed item that gives stat penalties under certain conditions that you can control (e.g. -2 to STR when in sunlight) you could use that to eliminate it.

Comment: That is an interesting and useful interpretation.  Thanks.

Comment: There must be some nonzero amount of CMD, right?  Otherwise a tiny-sized creature could trivially grapple and move their colossal-sized friend.

Comment: It does seem the AC penalty from DEX should apply, I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @MikeQ, given its "d20 vs. 10+bonus" format, regardless of whatever else a close reading of the rules reveals, I am reasonably certain that we can't eliminate the 10 even though I would want to for my purposes.